# Is it faster to compare String's, or byte arrays?

Tags: java, string, hadoop, arrays, hbase

So, might sound like an odd question, but is it faster to compare 2 String's, or byte[]'s (using [Arrays.equals()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D%29))? I'm working with Hadoop/Hbase, and I get byte[] as the value from Hbase, and I have a value that is passed in. Will it be faster to convert the value I get to a String and compare? Or compare them as to byte arrays?

Comment: did you try and profile/benchmark it?

Comment: No, I haven't, I'm asking here since others may already have done something similar, I just can't seem to find it via Google.

Comment: You need to clean up this question a bit.  Is the value passed in a String or a byte array, and is the point to have equivalent strings or equivalent bytes?  And if it is strings stored as bytes then there needs to be information encoding, even if it to say that they are all the same encoding.

Comment: As I put in my comment to Suraj's answer, Hbase stores the String as a byte array, and I convert it to that use Bytes.toBytes(String) which is a Hbase class. In my MapReduce Job, I'm then given a String that I need to compare the value from Hbase to. I can either convert the Hbase value to a String, use String.equals(), or I can convert the String I'm given to a byte array and compare byte arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without actually testing this it would seem that Array.equals() is your friend.  To make a string you end up making a copy of the byte array in the String constructor, then you have to decode the unicode, which involves creating a decoder for the default Unicode encoding, and converting the byte array into a char array, then you have to do the equals, which involves iterating through every character in each of the strings.

So on a O() type calculation you already have to read every byte in the array to do the conversion to a character, so I'd say the complexity is worse for converting to String for equals.

Update:
Given the comments added to the question, it sounds like you are given a String and are using it to compare to multiple results in the MapReduce job.  In this case it seems that there is one conversion of the input String to bytes and them multiple byte array comparisons.  This seems faster than leaving the input String and converting every byte array returned in the job.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, You have to consider whether both the strings are of same encoding.
Then if you just want to have an equals check then go ahead with byte comparison. But if you want to have the **compareTo** behavior of String, then you may have to figure out how to know which string is greater or lesser, in which case I would prefer converting to String first and then compare.

If they are not of same encoding, then its better to create Strings and then compare as the decoding part will be done by String class itself.

Comment: Yea, encoded the same way in the byte[] (Using Hbase's Bytes.toByte()), and I don't need compareTo() functionality, just equals().

Comment: then go ahead with byte comparison. infact use Arrays.equals itself

Answer (score 1):

First, you should ask yourself if it really matters.  Given that you are dealing with HBase, and thus network communication, whatever you do may be completely swamped, time-wise. Like @Clint and @Suraj, I think your probably better off with fewer method calls (i.e. using Array.equals() ).  Just think of what has to happen when you do a String equals, and then add in the overhead of converting the byte-arrays to Strings.